# When more than one tests added to rest controller test why am I getting WebApplicationContext is required?

Tags: rest, maven, spring-mvc, testing, controller

This is very funny. When I ran my controller test with more than one tests I am getting the following error when i run it with maven, but works fine in eclipse Junit.`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.<init>(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:46)
    at com.akrilist.rest.web.akripost.controller.AbstractRestControllerTest.setup(AbstractRestControllerTest.java:32)
    at com.akrilist.rest.web.akripost.controller.AutoPostControllerTest.setup(AutoPostControllerTest.java:36)` Then I ran one test commenting the other alternately (commented testA then run testB, then commented testB then run testA) both are passing. I have no idea what is happening when I put both of then are active tests. if any of you have clue please let me know. I have put my classes here.

### AbstractRestControllerTest

```html
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestRestServiceConfig.class, WebAppConfig.class })
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class AbstractRestControllerTest {
 protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    /*@Inject
    protected UserAccountService userAccountServiceMock;*/

    @Before
    public void setup() {
       /* Mockito.reset(userAccountServiceMock);*/
     
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
     
    }
}
```

### AutoPostControllerTest

```html
public class AutoPostControllerTest extends AbstractRestControllerTest {

 @Autowired
 private AutoPostService autoPostServiceMock;
 @Autowired
 private AutoPostConverter autoPostConverterMock;

 @Before
 public void setup() {

  // Mockito.reset(autoPostServiceMock);
  // Mockito.reset(commentPostRepositoryMock);

  super.setup();
 }

 @Test
 public void testValidationErrorForNullProfileId() throws Exception {
  String description = TestUtil.createStringWithLength(501);
  AutoPost autoPost = new TestAutoPostBuilder().description(description).buildModel();
  mockMvc.perform(post("/auto/post").contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(autoPost))).andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
    .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
    // .andExpect(jsonPath("$[]", hasSize(1)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.type", is("validation failure")));

  verifyZeroInteractions(autoPostServiceMock);
 }

 @Test
 public void testGet_shouldReturnPost() throws Exception {
  String description = TestUtil.createStringWithLength(501);
  String postId = TestUtil.createStringWithLength(16);
  Integer profileId = 123456;
  TestAutoPostBuilder testAutoPostBuilder = new TestAutoPostBuilder();
  AutoPost post = testAutoPostBuilder.postId(postId).description(description).profileId(profileId).buildModel();

  when(autoPostServiceMock.get(postId)).thenReturn(post);
  when(autoPostConverterMock.convertTo(post)).thenReturn(testAutoPostBuilder.buildDto());
  mockMvc.perform(get("/auto/post/" + postId).contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.postId", is(postId))).andExpect(jsonPath("$.profileId", is(profileId))).andExpect(jsonPath("$.links", hasSize(1)));

  verify(autoPostServiceMock, times(1)).get(anyString());
  verifyNoMoreInteractions(autoPostServiceMock);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue. It was because of parallel configuration of maven-surefire-plugin. I changed its value to 'classes', so the issue is over. There are two ways we can fix this issue. One is

```
<parallel>classes</parallel>
<threadCount>10</threadCount>
```

other way annotating the test class with **@net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe**  that required sequential execution.